# Storing the guessed word in Hangman game

Tags: python

How can I store the users input from the hangman function, so every time the for loop runs it remembers the user has already guessed the letter.

When the hangman function runs the first time, if the user's input is 'gera', that's fine, it should then loop back for a fifth guess; the problem is if the user enters 'mo' now, it won't show like this gera _ _ mo, instead it'll print _ _ _ _ _ _ mo; forgetting the users previous 'gera' input. 
How can I store past inputs so the code recalls what was passed?

```
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):

    a = ""
    for char1 in secret_word:
        if char1 in letters_guessed:
                a += char1
        else: 
                a += "_ "

    print(a)







def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):

    a = string.ascii_lowercase
    for char1 in a:
        if char1 in letters_guessed:
           a = a.replace(char1,"")


    print(a)




def hangman(secret_word_user_to_guess):

    secret_word_user_to_guess = 'geranimo'

    for index in range(6,1,-1):
        print('You have', index,'guesses left.')
        #print('Available letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
        letters_guessed = input('Check a word: ')
        get_guessed_word(secret_word_user_to_guess, letters_guessed)
        print('Available letters:')
        get_available_letters(letters_guessed)
```

Comment: I'd use a set for the guesses

Comment: This question is so unclear... The title says *"Replacing a guessed **word** with an underscore."* yet the example shows *letters* being replaced instead of whole *words*. Even the example itself is confusing: `'apple'` -> `'_ pp_ e'` Why there is a space between `_` and `e` and why `e` was not replaced? Was it not in the list of guessed letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily:

```
result = ""
for char in secret_word:
    if char in letters_guessed:
        result += char
    else:
        result += "_"
```

Or, using a generator:

```
result = "".join(char if char in letters_guessed else "_" for char in secret_word)
```

BTW, `letters_guessed` could be a string (`"eikprs"`) or, if the order doesn't matter, a `set`: `set("eikprs")`.

---

You can also try this:

```
result = secret_word.translate("".maketrans(letters_guessed, "_" * len(letters_guessed)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve it like ForceBru already mentioned. But to add one with sets as proposed in the comments:

```
def g(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    letters = set(secret_word)
    guess = set(letters_guessed)
    for i in letters.difference(guess):
        secret_word=secret_word.replace(i,'_')
    print(secret_word)

secret_word = 'apple'
letters_guessed = ['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
print(g(secret_word, letters_guessed) ) #prints '_pp_e'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at your function, because there's a concept you don't appear to have:

```
def g(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    a = []
    for char1 in secret_word:    
        for thing in letters_guessed:
            if thing == char1:            
                a += thing
                break
            elif thing != char1:
                a[secret_word.index(char1)] == '_ '
                break
```

The line `for char1 in secret_word:` iterates over the word, pulling each character into `char` in turn. There's nothing wrong with this, and pretty much every solution will have to use it.

Next, you do `for thing in letters_guessed:`. There's a problem with this, as pointed out by @ForceBru, in that Python supplies the [`in` and `not in` operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=expressions#membership-test-operations) to do what you're trying to code by hand.

However, when you're just starting out it's okay to re-invent the wheel a few times. If nothing else, it helps you understand what's happening under the hood.

The thing I think you've missed, or misunderstood, is this: when you have `char1 == thing` you **know** something. You can absolutely state that "yes, this letter has been guessed" and you can proceed to show the letter.

But when that condition *isn't true* - when `char1 != thing` - you don't know anything. You can't simply say "oh, if that isn't true then draw an underscore" because *you aren't finished checking!*

Remember that the `for thing in letters_guessed:` loop is checking each of the letters that have been guessed. This means that even though this particular character in letters_guessed might not match the current character in the word, it's possible that some other character *will* match, so you have to keep looping.

Something like this:

```
for char1 in secret_word:
    for thing in letters_guessed:
        if thing == char1:
            a += thing
            break
    else: # 'else' after for means 'if no break command was run'
        a += '_'
```